# Asymptotic behaviour of Laplace transform

Tags: integration, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, asymptotics, laplace-transform

If the functions $x(t)$ and its derivatives $x'(t), x''(t), \ldots, x^n(t)$ are continuous* and $x(0^+) = x'(0^+) = x''(0^+) \ldots = x^{n-1}(0^+)=0$ ($0^+$ denotes the right side limit when the independent variable approaches 0) and they don't have continuity problems at $0$, then the Laplace Transform of nth derivative of the function $x$ is

$$
\mathscr{L}\left [ x^{n}(t) \right ]= s^n X(s)
$$

*Note: the nth derivative $x^n$ can be piecewise continuous.

The terms $-s^{n-1}x(0^+)-s^{n-2}x'(0^+) \ldots -s x^{n-2}(0^+) - x^{n-1}(0^+)$ are 0.

$\lim_{s \to \infty} s^n X(s) = 0$

This implies that $X(s) \to 0$ faster than

$$\frac{1}{s^n}$$

Therefore

$$X(s) = o \left (\frac {1}{s^n}  \right )$$

a) Why does the function $x(t)$ and its derivatives $x'(t)$, $x"(t)$, $\ldots x^n(t)$ need to be continuous and $x^n(t)$ could also be piecewise continuous?

b) Why can't the function $x(t)$ and its derivatives $x'(t)$, $x"(t)$, $\ldots x^n(t)$ have discontinuity problems at 0?  Here, one is taking the right-side limit when the variable approaches 0. So I think that it doesn't matter if these functions have discontinuities at $t=0$.

**Edit:**

If the functions $x(t)$ and its derivatives $x'(t)$, $x"(t)$, $\ldots , x^n(t)$ are continuous.

And  $x(0)$ = $x'(0)$= $x"(0) \ldots = x^{n-1}(0)=0$ (Here I replaced $(0^+)$ by $(0)$)

and they don't have discontinuity problems at $t=0$

then the $\mathscr{L}\{x^{(n)}\}(s) = s^{n}X(s) - s^{n-1}x(0) - \ldots - x^{(n-1)}(0)$ exists.

In this case. It is necessary that the functions don't have discontinuity problems at 0. Because if they do one can't evaluate the function or its derivatives up to $x^{(n-1)}$ at t=0.

But if one says that if $x(t)$ and its derivatives $x'(t)$, $x"(t)$, $\ldots , x^n(t)$ are continuous.

And  $x(0^+)$ = $x'(0^+)$= $x"(0^+) \ldots = x^{n-1}(0^+)=0$.

Do you need the third assumption "and they don't have discontinuity problems at $t=0$", or you can completely remove it?

Because one is taking the right-side limits of the function $x(t)$ and its derivatives when $t$ approaches zero.

Note: The function is not continuous when it says that the function has discontinuity problems.

Comment: They're probably using the Riemann integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple case.** If $x$ is $n-1$ times differentiable at $0$, then, according to Taylor's theorem

$$
x(t) = x(0) + \dot{x}(0)t + \frac{\ddot{x}(0)}{2!}t^2 + \ldots + 
\frac{x^{(n-1)}(0)}{(n-1)!}t^{n-1} + r(t),
$$

for $t\geq 0$ and $r(t) = o(t^{n-1})$ as $t\to 0$.

Under the assumption that $x(0) = \dot{x}(0) = \ldots = x^{(n-1)}(0) = 0$, we have $x(t) = o(t^{n-1})$ as $t\to 0$. This means that for all $c>0$, there is a $T>0$ so that $|x(t)| \leq c t^{n-1}$ for $t\in [0, T)$. If we multiply by $e^{-s\tau}$ and integrate from $0$ to $\infty$, we obtain

$$X(s) = o\left(\tfrac{1}{s^{n}}\right) \text{ as } s\to\infty,$$

where $s\in\mathbb{R}$.

Just to be clear, this is because

\begin{align}
X(s) {}={}& \int_0^\infty e^{-s\tau}x(\tau) \mathrm{d}\tau
\\
{}={}& 
\int_0^\infty e^{-\xi}x(\xi/s) \mathrm{d}\xi
\\
{}\approx{}& 
\int_0^\infty e^{-\xi} \cdot o\left(|{\xi}/{s}|^{n-1}\right)\mathrm{d}\xi \text{ as } s\to \infty
\\
{}={}& o\left(\tfrac{1}{s^{n}}\right) \text{ as } s\to \infty
\end{align}

**Proposition.** Suppose that $x$ is $n-1$ times differentiable for all $t\in (0, t_0)$ for some $t_0 > 0$. Suppose that the following limits exist and are equal to zero: $x(0^+) = \ldots = x^{(n-1)}(0^+) = 0$. Suppose also that $x$ has a Laplace transform, which is denoted by $X$. Then, we have that

\begin{align}
X(s) = o \left(\tfrac{1}{s^{n}}\right), \text{ as } s\to\infty,
\end{align}

with $s\in\mathbb{R}$.

*Proof.* Since  $x(0^+) = \ldots = x^{(n-1)}(0^+) = 0$, for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $T>0$ such that $|x(t)| < \epsilon$, $|\dot{x}(t)| < \epsilon$, $\ldots$, $|x^{(n-1)}(t)| < \epsilon$ for all $t \in (0, T)$. Then, choose a $\zeta \in (0, T)$ and apply Taylor's theorem on $x$ at $\zeta$:

\begin{align}
x(t) = x(\zeta) + \dot{x}(t)(\zeta)(t-\zeta) + \frac{\ddot{x}(\zeta)}{2}(t-\zeta)^2 + \ldots + \frac{x^{(n-1)}}{(n-1)!}(t-\zeta)^{n-1} + r(t),
\end{align}

where $r(t) = o(|t-\zeta|^{n-1})$. But then,

\begin{align}
x(t) = \underbrace{\epsilon \left(1 + T + \tfrac{T^2}{2} + \ldots + \tfrac{T^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\right)}_{\beta} + r(t),
\end{align}

and proceeding as above we conclude that $X(s) = o \left(\tfrac{1}{s^{n}}\right)$.  $\Box$

**About the assumptions.** In the above statement we did not use the assumptions of piecewise continuity, although these are often imposed (along side exponential order) to guarantee that $x$ has a Laplace transform. By the way, since $x$ is $n-1$ times differentiable on $(0, t_0)$, its derivatives up to order $n-2$ must be continuous, so only $x^{(n-1)}$ can be assumed to be discontinuous.

If this is an exercise in a textbook, I guess that the assumption that all derivatives are continuous is given to allow to use the fact that $\mathscr{L}\{x^{(n)}\}(s) = s^{n}X(s) - s^{n-1}x(0^+) - \ldots - x^{(n-1)}(0^+)$, which can also be used to prove the above result.

**Update.** Here is an example of a function $x(t)$ that satisfies the assumptions of the above proposition, but is not continuous at $0$.

$$
x(t) = \begin{cases}
1, &\text{ if } t = 0
\\
t^2\sin(t), & \text{ if } 0 < t \leq 1
\\
e^{-t}, & \text{ if } t > 1
\end{cases}
$$

This has a discontinuity at $t=0$ (it doesn't matter) and another discontinuity at $t=1$ (again, it doesn't matter). It is continuous and infinitely many times differentiable over $(0,1)$ and

$$
x(0^+) = \dot{x}(0^+) = \ddot{x}(0^+) = 0,
$$

but $x^{(3)}(0^+) = 6 \neq 0$. Note that $1 = x(0) \neq x(0^+) = 0$.

Then,

$$
X(s) = o(1/s^3), \text{ as } s\to \infty.
$$

Comment: If $x(t)$ is supported on $t \ge 0$ and it is $n$-times differentiable **and** $x^{(n)}(t)e^{-ct} \in L^1$ then $\mathcal{L}[x^{(n)}(t)](s)=s^n \mathcal{L}[x(t)](s)\to 0$ uniformly as $\Re(s) \to \infty$. Conversely if $s^3 \mathcal{L}[x(t)](s)\to 0$ uniformly as $\Re(s) \to \infty$ then $s \mathcal{L}[x(t)](s)$ is $L^1$ on vertical lines so that $x'(t)= \frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{a-i\infty}^{a+i\infty} s \mathcal{L}[x(t)](s) e^{st}ds$ is bounded and continuous. Thus OP's statement fails with $x(t) = \sin(e^t)e^{-1/t}1_{t > 0}$ which is $C^\infty$.

Comment: @reuns Thanks for the comment. Function $x(t)=\sin(e^t)e^{-1/t}1_{t>0}$ has the property $0=x(0^+) = \dot{x}(0^+) = \ldots$ for all derivatives. Its Laplace transform goes to 0 as $s \to \infty$ as $o(1/s^k)$ for any $k$. Isn't it?

Comment: Oh, I see (the penny dropped). In my answer I assumed $s\to\infty$ over the reals. It would be nice if you could also provide an answer.

Comment: For the asymptotic on the real line : if $x(t)$ is smooth and bounded then $x(t) = y(z)+z(t)$ where $z(t)$ is bounded supported on $t > 1$ and $y(t)$ is smooth and supported on $[0,2]$, thus for every $n, y^{(n}(t)\in L^1$ so the Laplace transform of $y(t)$ decays faster than $s^{-n}$ uniformly as $\Re(s) \to \infty$, and the Laplace transform of $z(t)$ is bounded by $C |e^{-s}|$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. About the assumptions in the OP I have doubts if they are right. Can you check my edit in the OP?

Comment: @roy212 The phrase "discontinuity problems" is not very rigorous. Do you mean that they are continuous? Function $x$ and its derivatives do not need to be continuous at $0$. In fact, the derivatives may not be defined at $0$. Of course, if $x$ is $n-1$ times diff/ble on $(0, T)$ for some T, all derivatives up to order $n-2$ must be continuous on $(0,T)$, but $x^{(n-1)}$ is allowed to be discontinuous. Note that this is on $(0, T)$ (close to $0$). We don't have what happens beyond that point so long as $x$ has a Laplace transform, so it is allowed to be piecewise smooth/continuous.

Comment: I mean that they are not continuous at zero. If the function or the derivatives are not defined at 0, then you can't evaluate  $x(0)$ and the derivatives $x'(0), x"(0)$...to $x^{(x-1)}(0)$ in the Laplace transform of the nth derivative, $ \mathscr{L}\{x^{(n)}\}(s) = s^{n}X(s) - s^{n-1}x(0) - \ldots - x^{(n-1)}(0)$.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. They don't need to be continuous *at* zero. They should be continuous for all $t\in (0, T)$ for some $T>0$. This is different from continuity at zero. Besides, you don't need $x(0)$, $x'(0)$, $x''(0)$ and so on - you only need $x(0^+)$, $x'(0^+)$, $x''(0^+)$ etc. Mind, however, that $x(t)$, being a time domain function (usually) is *defined* at zero, but again, this doesn't mean that it's continuous at zero. Additionally, it is $\mathscr{L}\{x^{(n)}\} = s^n X(s) - s^{n-1}x(0^+) - \ldots - x^{(n-1)}(0^+)$.

Comment: Thanks. This is what my edit was about.If I understood it rightly, you skip the discontinuity at 0 by evaluating the function and its derivatives at the right-side limit. Isn't it? I have another doubt. If the function $x(t)$ is not continuous at some finite number of points. The first derivative won't be continuous at some finite number of points. And the third derivative the same, etc. So the function and its derivatives will be piecewise continuous. Won't the Laplace transform exist in this case? Why ". They should be continuous for all $t\in (0, T)$ for some $T > 0$"?

Comment: @roy212 First part: yes, that's it. Second part: We assume that $x$ and its derivatives exist and are continuous on an interval $(0, T)$. This is a very weak assumption - otherwise $x$ will be *nowhere continuous* close to $0$. Note that you can take $T$ to be arbitrarily small. If a derivative is discontinuous at $0<t_1< t_2< \ldots< t_k$, simply choose $0<T<t_1$. If $x$ is not piecewise continuous and of exponential order, it may not have a Laplace transform. I will update my answer with an example.

Comment: Oh, right, I understand now. Yes, you're right. There's no need to impose such an assumption on the derivatives. You only need to assume that this is the case for $x$. If you like we can move this discussion to the chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93570/discussion-between-pantelis-sopasakis-and-roy212).

Comment: Sorry. I've just seen your message.